# Can I copy NSURLRequest and reuse it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using api with oauth2, and need to refresh the access token when it expires. So I want to resent the request after the request is refreshed. I am concerning whether the NSURLConnection will change the http request object. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked out the [URL loading guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-156642)?  It has this in a box in the text:

> When a client application initiates a connection or download using an instance of NSMutableURLRequest, a deep copy is made of the request. Changes made to the initiating request have no effect once a download has been initialized.

So you can reuse your request as much as you like without fear of modification.  `NSURLConnection` works with a copy of it.

Comment: What about when using NSURLSession APIs?